# Error computing frontogenesis with mpcalc

Tags: python, metpy

My goal is to compute frontogenesis at a given pressure level using the mpcalc.frontogenesis method.

I have read in the relevant data from NOMADS:

```
t7 = data['temp'].sel(lev=700.0,lat=lats,lon=lons)
u7 = data['u'].sel(lev=700.0,lat=lats,lon=lons).squeeze()*1.94384449
v7 = data['v'].sel(lev=700.0,lat=lats,lon=lons).squeeze()*1.94384449
h7 = data['gph'].sel(lev=700.0,lat=lats,lon=lons).squeeze()
```

Computed the relevant coordinate/grid spacing values:

```
x, y = t7.metpy.coordinates('x', 'y')
dx, dy = mpcalc.lat_lon_grid_deltas(lons, lats)
lat, lon = xr.broadcast(y, x)
```

Tagged each array with units:

```
t7u = t7.values * units.degC
u7u = u7.values * units.knots
v7u = v7.values * units.knots
```

Then I go to compute FGEN:

```
h7_fgen = mpcalc.frontogenesis(t7u,u7u,v7u,dx,dy,dim_order='xy')
```

which produces the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (359,219) (358,220)
```

The shapes of the temperature, u, and v arrays respectively are:

```
(220, 360)
(220, 360)
(220, 360)
```

So while dx and dy will understandably have lengths n-1, I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: While this looks like a dimension order mismatch, would you be able to post the particular NOMADS data source so as to make your example fully reproducible? Thanks!

Comment: I am accessing data from [here](https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/dods/gfs_0p25_1hr/gfs20201230/gfs_0p25_1hr_12z) using xr.open_dataset(url). I have then pased the dataset with metpy 'data=ds.metpy.parse_cf' let me know if any other information would be helpful and thanks so much for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If pulling data directly from the NOMADS GFS source, it looks like your data should be in yx dimension order (which is also the order assumed by MetPy's `lat_lon_grid_deltas` function). And so, I would presume that something got messed up in the script with regards to dimension ordering. Resolving this, and making additional use of some of MetPy's xarray integration features to clean up the implementation, we have:

### Pre MetPy v1.0

```py
# Imports
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
from metpy.units import units
import xarray as xr

# Open data and parse for CRS
data = xr.open_dataset('http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/dods/gfs_0p25_1hr/gfs20201230/gfs_0p25_1hr_12z').metpy.parse_cf()

# Subset out the desired data
# Note that this leaves in time, but that can also be selected out if only
# one time is needed and you want to have smaller data arrays to compute on
t7 = data['tmpprs'].sel(lev=700.0,lat=slice(15, 70),lon=slice(220, 310))
u7 = data['ugrdprs'].sel(lev=700.0,lat=slice(15, 70),lon=slice(220, 310)).squeeze()
v7 = data['vgrdprs'].sel(lev=700.0,lat=slice(15, 70),lon=slice(220, 310)).squeeze()
h7 = data['hgtprs'].sel(lev=700.0,lat=slice(15, 70),lon=slice(220, 310)).squeeze()

# Clean up the xarray metadata for MetPy's use, since provided data is missing
# the units attribute
t7.attrs['units'] = 'K'
u7.attrs['units'] = v7.attrs['units'] = 'm/s'
h7.attrs['units'] = 'm'

# Get grid deltas
dx, dy = mpcalc.grid_deltas_from_dataarray(t7)

# Compute frontogenesis
h7_fgen = mpcalc.frontogenesis(t7, u7, v7, dx, dy)
```

### Post MetPy v1.0

In MetPy v1.0, the grid arguments are automatically extracted from DataArray inputs, and so, this can be simplified to

```py
# Imports
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
from metpy.units import units
import xarray as xr

# Open data and parse for CRS
data = xr.open_dataset('http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/dods/gfs_0p25_1hr/gfs20201230/gfs_0p25_1hr_12z').metpy.parse_cf()

# Subset out the desired data
t7 = data['tmpprs'].sel(lev=700.0,lat=slice(15, 70),lon=slice(220, 310))
u7 = data['ugrdprs'].sel(lev=700.0,lat=slice(15, 70),lon=slice(220, 310)).squeeze()
v7 = data['vgrdprs'].sel(lev=700.0,lat=slice(15, 70),lon=slice(220, 310)).squeeze()
h7 = data['hgtprs'].sel(lev=700.0,lat=slice(15, 70),lon=slice(220, 310)).squeeze()

# Clean up the xarray metadata for MetPy's use, since provided data is missing
# the units attribute
t7.attrs['units'] = 'K'
u7.attrs['units'] = v7.attrs['units'] = 'm/s'
h7.attrs['units'] = 'm'

# Compute frontogenesis
h7_fgen = mpcalc.frontogenesis(t7, u7, v7)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this Jon! I pasted that into my script and sadly metpy is insisting t,u,v all still don't have units. I tried using the array=array*units.[unit] syntax but no luck there either. Any ideas? Should I open a separate question assuming this issue has been fixed?

Comment: There may have been an issue in where you had pasted this code into your script (where the variables are no longer what my code above expects them to be, and so are applying an incorrect operation). Or, there may be a difference in library version (such as xarray or Pint) causing issues. Perhaps you could post what you have so far, along with your versions of NumPy, xarray, Pint, and Metpy, on MetPy's GitHub discussions (https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/discussions), which is a bit better of a format for back-and-forth troubleshooting than StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I have opened a [discussion](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/discussions/1641)